# How to fade between texts in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my project, I have a div element that changes text every so often. When the text is changed, I want to completely fade out the old text, and then fade in the new text in the same position.

Although I've gotten it to work for the most part, a new paragraph element is being created before the other one is completely gone. Is there a way for me to wait for an element to be completely faded before the other is added?

Here's a codepen to show what I mean: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qppgzz.

Notice how the old `<p :key="index">{{ text }}</p>` is not completely transitioned off before the new one is added.

Comment: add `mode="out-in"` to your `transition` component. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transition-Modes

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for!